# Error in the following process: unzip .pptx -> modify content -> rezip to .pptx

Tags: xml, powerpoint, openxml

I am trying to unzip a Microsoft Office file (.docx and .pptx), modify some content, and then rezip to a new .docx or .pptx file.

I was successful in doing this with a .docx file:

1) `$ unzip .../test.docx`

2) modify some content in the `document.xml` file

3) `$ zip -r rezipped.docx *`

Using the above process I can then successfully open the new document (rezipped.docx) in Microsoft Word and see the changed content.

I then tried the same process for .pptx but have not found success.

1) `$ unzip .../test.pptx`

2) modify some content in the `slide1.xml` file
For example, a simple text change: `<a:t>Hello World</a:t>` to `<a:t>Hi World</a:t>`

3) `$ zip -r rezipped.pptx *`

When I try to open rezipped.pptx in Microsoft PowerPoint 2008 for Mac Version 12.0 I get the following error message:

> There was an error accessing Macintosh rezipped.pptx

However, I can open the file without any issues in Keynote.

I tried the same experiment but I only modified a file in the `docProps` folder (i.e. app.xml or core.xml) and I was able to rezip it and open it with no problem in Microsoft PowerPoint. So it is only if I edit a file in the `ppt` folder that I experience this issue.

**What is causing this corruption when I edit the contents of slide1.xml and then rezip the files?** Is there another file somewhere in the .pptx structure that is tracking content/modifications?

I also tried resetting the modified date of the file after changing it to see if this had any effect but it did not: `touch -m -t 198001010000 slide1.xml`

Comment: You haven't mentioned what edits you've made to the contents of slide1.xml  If you change it in ways that invalidate the xml, PowerPoint will, reasonably, refuse to open it.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg nothing that invalidates the xml. Just a simple text change, for example `<a:t>Hello World</a:t>` to `<a:t>Hi World</a:t>`

Comment: Please try diagnostics I suggest at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23716478/1031689

Comment: @JasonPlutext thanks for your suggestion. However, 7-zip seems to be a Windows utility and I do not currently have access to a Windows machine.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I was able to get it working using another zip tool, so I guess the Mac command line zip tool process is at fault, as you suspected.

Comment: Following upon your reply to JasonPlutext: I've had problems with PPTX files going corrupt after unzipping/rezipping them with WinZIP.  IIRC, it was trying to make a backup copy of the file I was copying back into the ZIP archive. Same problem with the Mac's built-in compression tools. Perhaps StuffIt or the like would do a more reliable job of it.

Answer (score 5):

This answer applies to Mac OS.

I was able to do it with Finder on Mac. The trick is to select the contents of the folder instead of the folder itself. So if your unzipped presentation `mypres` has folders `_rels`, `docProps`, and so on,

1. open the `mypres` folder.
2. Select all the items. (with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, for example)
3. Use the right-click (<kbd>command</kbd>-click) context menu to "Compress Items."
4. Change the name of the new file from `Archive.zip` to `mypres.pptx`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked in Fedora 30/Gnome 3.32/Nautilus/File Roller

Answer (score 3):

Try rezipping it with 7zip. Make sure to not include any additional directory. I was able to rezip my unzipped PPTX-File after editing Textcontent in slide1.xml